# Subset of Plane with specific property

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that no $3$ points in $S$ are collinear and $|S| = \infty$. Show that there is a $T \subset S$, $|T| = \infty$ such that no point in $T$ is a convex combination of other points in $T$.

Comment: How would you start?

Comment: I was thinking this might be related to a theorem from Ramsey theory. If I finitely color $c : \mathbb{N}^{(r)} \rightarrow [k]$, then I can find $X \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $c$ is constant on $X^{(r)}$, that is, the $r$-sets of $X$. But I do not know if $S$ is countable. The convex combination condition makes it a bit tricky.